# How can I convert a save file for a retail game into a save file for the digital version of the same game?

Tags: ps3, persona-4-arena

I bought Persona 4 Arena for the PS3 back in August and logged dozens of hours in the game in order to to unlock all the single player content. Two weeks ago, I decided to buy the digital version because I still play it to this day and wanted the convenience of having it on my hard drive. Unfortunately, after buying and playing it, the original save file wouldn’t work as the files are named differently (one is Persona 4 ARENA, the other is Persona 4 ARENA [DL]) and Sony wouldn’t give me a refund.

I got a [tip on how to convert my original save file](http://www.neogaf.net/forum/showpost.php?p=61058237&postcount=51) into the new one and I even found a [video showing this process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpfuQEQw9uw%E2%80%8E). However, there are some differences that are impeding me to do so. My save folder includes the following files:

- ICON0.PNG
- PARAM.PFD
- PARAM.SFO
- PIC1.PNG
- SYSTEM.DAT

I assumed the SYSTEM.DAT file was the equivalent of the STATE file from the video, so I followed the same steps but got an error while trying to load the file. Is there any way to fix this? Are there any tools that will allow me to play the digital version with my old retail file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. A friend of mine had the same problem and after days of wondering how to get it we finally realized that the product memory is not compatible with the old one. Sorry.